# How to round double to nearest whole number and then convert to a float?

Tags: java, rounding

I am using java.util.Random to generate a random gaussian. I need to convert this gaussian to a float value. However gaussian is a double, so I need some way to either round then convert it to a float. I need to round to the nearest whole number, rounding up. Here is my question: How?

Comment: "I need to convert this gaussian to a float value." ... " I need to round to the nearest whole number" ... Do you want a float or an integer?

Comment: Do you want to round up, or do you want to round to the nearest whole number?

Comment: Do you want to round to the nearest whole number, or round up?  Those are incompatible statements.  e.g.  How would you round 3.4?  Nearest whole number is 3, rounding up is 4.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`float b = (float)Math.ceil(a);`
or
`float b = (float)Math.round(a);`

Depending on whether you meant "round to the nearest whole number" (round) or "round up" (ceil).

Beware of loss of precision in converting a double to a float, but that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, exactly what I was asking for

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick example:

```
public class One {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = 4.56777;
        System.out.println( new Float( Math.round(a)) );

    }

}
```

*the result and output will be: **`5.0`**

the closest upper bound Float to the starting value of `double a = 4.56777`

in this case the use of round is recommended since it takes in `double` values and provides whole `long` values*

Regards

Comment: `(float)Math.round(a)` is many times as efficient in both time and space.

Comment: Agreed.

You should use `Float a = new Float("3.14")` only when you need access to the inherited methods of the super-class Object, such as `clone, toString, equals` and so on. 

`float a = (float) 3.14;` behaves very poorly in a OOP approach.

Comment: I don't know what `Float a = new Float("3.14")` has to do with it. Neither the OP nor I nor you have said anything about it, or about OOP either for that matter.

Comment: It was a supporting argument for your post! Yes casting to float is efficient but Float wrapping has it's benefits, just wanted to remind that to any coin, there are to sides. Regards.

Comment: But it doesn't support my post, and the part about OOP contradicts it. Make up your mind.

Comment: _go for_ `float` in this case. I only mentioned the `Float` because I was not sure what the user would have to do after getting his result. But I can see that it ends there and, yes, cast to `float` is better in any way for his needs. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

[Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth:

the closest integer to any given input as shown in the following table can be calculated using Math.ceil or Math.floor depending of the distance between the input and the next integer

```
+-------+--------+
| input | output |
+-------+--------+
|     1 |      0 |
|     2 |      0 |
|     3 |      5 |
|     4 |      5 |
|     5 |      5 |
|     6 |      5 |
|     7 |      5 |
|     8 |     10 |
|     9 |     10 |
+-------+--------+
```

---

```
private int roundClosest(final int i, final int k) {
    int deic = (i % k);
    if (deic <= (k / 2.0)) {
        return (int) (Math.floor(i / (double) k) * k);
    } else {
        return (int) (Math.ceil(i / (double) k) * k);
    }
}
```