# How to divide a float number and cast the result to integer in Android

Tags: android, casting, integer

---

### Problem

Suppose `int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount()` returns a number that is a multiple of three plus one, e.g. `4`, `7`, `10`, `13`....

I want to add two to that `childCount` and divide it by three to get my desired result for the number of my list, e.g. `(7 + 2) / 3` should give an answer of `3`, but I don't whether it would be `2` or `4` just because the error when doing the float operation. So I do it like this to make sure I get `3` as the result:

```
int numberOfCells = (int) ((linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f);
```

Is it correct?

---

### Update

Because there are two sub view (lines) in my linear layout following each relative layout (also the child of linear layout). But the last relative layout has no lines following. So what I wanna get the number of relative layouts, that is also the number of cells of the list that I'm gonna make.

---

### Update 2

Is that statement,

```
int numberOfCells = (int) ((linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f);
```

equivalent to

```
int numberOfCells = (int) Math.floor((linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f);
```

Comment: so you want to get the result as 3 if the child count is 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235076/how-to-round-double-to-nearest-whole-number-and-then-convert-to-a-float. not sure i understand ur question fully

Comment: Please have a look of my update.

Comment: Both statements in Update 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Oh by the way, @vikram, is there any official description about how the cast mechanism works? If not, where did you know they're equivalent?

Comment: I know they are equivalent because of the following reasoning: Common part of both equations is `(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f`. Let's evaluate all possible outcomes of this. Here: `linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2` will return a `+ve integer`. `(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3` will either evaluate to `zero` or `+ve integer`. Adding `0.5f` to `zero` or a `+ve integer` will result in either `0.5f` or `+x.5f`(where x is some +ve integer). So, the result of `(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f` will be `(0.5f or +x.5f)`.

Comment: Now, in case of first equation, we have: `(int)(0.5f or +x.5f)`. Casting a `float` or a `double` to an `int` returns the integer part of the `float` or `double`. Possible outcomes for first equation: `(0 or +x)`. In the second case we have: `(int) Math.floor(0.5f or +x.5f)`. `Math.floor(double)` returns `the most positive integer value less than or equal to the argument.` So, `Math.floor(0.5f or +x.5f)` will be: `(closest +ve integer less than 0.5f) = 0` OR `(closest +ve integer less than +x.5f) = +x`.

Comment: Since, `Math.floor()` returns an integer, casting the result to `(int)` is redundant. Possible outcomes for second equation: `0 or +x`. Both equations have the same outcome. Hence, they are equivalent.

Comment: What is `+ve integer`

Comment: "Casting a `float` or a `double` to an `int` returns the integer part of the `float` or `double`." Is this behavior specific to Java or is is universal among other languages like C, Objective-C...

Comment: To @vikram: please move your comment to an answer so that I can mark it as accepted

Comment: Hi, I was not notified about your messages about `+ve integer` and `casting` because of the missing @username. Sorry about `+ve integer`: it is a short form of `positive integer`. Similarly, I use `-ve integer` for `negative integer`. About casting: No, this behavior is not specific to Java, but it is not universal either. Its similar in c, objective-c and c++. And, I have updated the answer below with explanation from comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that statement,
>
> **int numberOfCells = (int) ((linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 +
>   0.5f);**
>
> equivalent to
>
> **int numberOfCells = (int) Math.floor((linearLayout.getChildCount() +
>   2) / 3 + 0.5f);**

Yes.

The reasoning:

Common part of both equations is:

```
(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f
```

Let's evaluate all possible outcomes of this.

Here: **linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2** will always be a `+ve integer`. **(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3** will either evaluate to `zero`(when `linearLayout.getChildCount()` returns `zero`) or `+ve integer`. Adding **0.5f** to `zero` or a `+ve integer` will result in either **0.5f** or **+x.5f**(where `x` is some +ve integer).

So, the result of **(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3 + 0.5f** will be **(0.5f or +x.5f)**.

Now, in case of `first equation`, we have: **(int)(0.5f or +x.5f)**. Casting a `float` or a `double` to an `int` returns the integer part of the float or double.

Possible outcomes for first equation: **(0 or +x)**.

For the `second equation`, we have: **(int) Math.floor(0.5f or +x.5f)**. `Math.floor(double)` returns the most positive integer value less than or equal to the argument. So, **Math.floor(0.5f or +x.5f)** will be: `(closest +ve integer less than 0.5f) = 0.0` OR `(closest +ve integer less than +x.5f) = +x.0`. Casting them to an `int` will result in (0 or +x).

Possible outcomes for second equation: **(0 or +x)**.

Both equations evaluate to an identical expression. Hence, they are equivalent.

---

How about using the `remainder`? For example, let's say:

```
int remainder = (linearLayout.getChildCount()) % 3;

int numberOfCells;

switch (remainder) {
    case 1:
        // linearLayout.getChildCount() returned 1, 4, 7, 10......
        numberOfCells = (linearLayout.getChildCount() + 2) / 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        // linearLayout.getChildCount() returned 2, 5, 8, 11......
        numberOfCells = (linearLayout.getChildCount() + 1) / 3;
        break;
    default:
        // linearLayout.getChildCount() returned a (+ve) multiple of 3......
        numberOfCells = (linearLayout.getChildCount()) / 3;
        break;
}
```