# How to get integer of a value?

Tags: java, android, integer, return-value, rounding

How to round up a decimal number to a whole number?

So for example when it is 1.25 rounds to 1  or -3.25 rounds to -3 etc

Comment: Have you googled it before asking question here

Comment: try using Math.round()

see more explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235076/how-to-round-double-to-nearest-whole-number-and-then-convert-to-a-float

Comment: That's way too easy. Do some research yourself. It's a bit annoying that people do not spend their time in researching but expect others to spend time on answering such very easy questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math round java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210491/math-round-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want decimal part do this .

```
double value = 1.25;
int i = (int)value;
```

if you want to round value , do this

```
Math.round(value);
```

Comment: see the output here.https://ideone.com/DilYJP

Comment: @downvoter. please specify why you downvote this.?. whats wrong in this code.?

Comment: Your code is wrong because if value is 1.25 it's fine we got 1 but what happens when the value will be 1.75?

Comment: it depend on the situation what the user want.as i gues he need to remove the decimal part like the input he provide.

Comment: Well he said he wanted to 'round up' the number so I think it is specified explicitly.

Comment: he said round to a whole number.he didnt mension round number to ceil and floor value.

Comment: Rounding is always to a whole number. Your answer is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round(float number)` method [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) if you want to round it. If you want to cut decimal part just cast it to int.

Answer (score 0):

A small trick I've learned during the years is just adding the value 0.5 to the value you want to round. After you did that, you can round it to an integer.

It's a generic workaround, which will work with alot of programming languages.

I dont know much about Java, but I think you will find a round-Method in the API. The package should be Math.

Edit:\

To round UP you could just add 1 instead of the value 0.5.